# React router routes to wrong component with params

Tags: reactjs, typescript, routes, react-router

I am trying to use `react-router` to route toa. user profile page.

My User row component is as follows :

```
render() {

        return (
            <div className="userrow">
                <div className="userrow-username">
                    {this.props.name}
                </div>
                <div>
                    <Link to={`/profile/${this.props.username}`} style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
                        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" size="small">
                            View Profile
                        </Button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The router:

```
public render() {

    return (this.state.loading === true) ? <h1>Loading</h1> : (

      <BrowserRouter>

        <div>
          <HeaderNav />

          <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path={routes.LANDING} component={LandingPage} />
            <Route exact={true} path={routes.SIGN_UP} component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact={true} path={routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />
            <Route exact={true} path={routes.PASSWORD_FORGET} component={PasswordForget} />
            <Route path={routes.USER} component={UserList} />
            <Route path={routes.PROJECT} component={Project} projectName='Nakul' />
            <Route path={routes.HOME} component={Home} />
            <Route exact={true} path="/profile/:username" component={UserProfile} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>

    );
  }
```

I also have some protected routes which I have added as consumers to firebase auth. I can share the code if necessary, but I don't see that as the issue here.

The problem is, when I route to `http://localhost:3000/profile/hellonakul` I get redirected to `home` which is `/` path .

Instead I should be routed to my `UserProfile` component, which isn't happening.

EDIT:
routes:

```
export const SIGN_UP = "/signup";
export const LOGIN = "/login";
export const LANDING = "/landing";
export const HOME = "/";
export const ACCOUNT = "/account";
export const PASSWORD_FORGET = "/password_forget";
export const PROJECT = "/project";
export const USER = "/user";
```

Comment: What is `routes.USER` and other variables value?

Comment: Added the routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that the Home route must be `exact={true}` too.

Edit: I think in your case, only the Home route needs an `exact={true}` attribute. This attribute is used to solve conflicts between similar routes.